# I have reached the limit of uptime checks on google stackdriver. Need to increase it

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I have reached the limit of uptime checks on google stackdriver. Need to increase it. Could you please help me how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can have up to 100 [uptime checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/#top_of_page) per Workspace. I recommend you to open a [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui) and our engineers will response you over there.